# How to change my openedx platform name?

Tags: openedx

I installed my instance of openedx and now want to customize the name of my platform.
[image]

How to do so ?

Comment: Given the high level of down votes on this #openedx.... thanks to explain your downvote briefly so I may improve / remove the question if indeed needed.

Comment: is the `LMS_CFG` envronment variable defined on your instance?  You can find that out by doing: `echo $LMS_CFG`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the Platform name

1. open `/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/envs/common.py`
2. edit `PLATFORM_NAME = "edX"` with the appropriate name
3. open `app/edxapp/lms.env.json`
4. edit `PLATFORM_NAME = "edX"` with the appropriate name
5. Restart the LMS

Answer (score 2):

While @hugo-lopez answer solved the problem, but you can check the current configuration before changing **PLATFORM_NAME** in /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/envs/common.py. You can also check your current configuration because sometimes you forgot to restart LMS.

```
python manage.py lms shell --settings devstack_docker
from django.conf import settings
settings.PLATFORM_NAME
```

I was using Juniper release, so modifying **lms.env.json** not worked for me. So, I modify PLATFORM_NAME in **/edx/etc/lms.yml** and **/edx/etc/studio.yml**.